# How do I use 出来る in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

日本語の話すを出来ます。
Does this sentence make sense? I'm not sure if I can say that or whether it's grammatically correct. I also don't really know how to use the 出来る verb, can someone help?

Comment: Related [What is the proper way of saying "can" about an action?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69032)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of saying "can" about an action?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69032/what-is-the-proper-way-of-saying-can-about-an-action)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
日本語の話すを出来ます。
```

Sentence above is grammatically incorrect. Correct will be as below.

```
日本語を話すことができます。
```

Check when to use `を` and when to use `の`.
https://linguapsych.com/japanese-particles/

The particle `が` always goes immediately after a noun.

`話す` is a verb, but `話すこと` makes it a noun.

Also you can check grammar by self too using some sites.
https://bunpo-check.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot ❤️❤️