# Is there any difference/nuances between られます and できます and if so what is it?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

This question first came to me when I saw the sentence:

> 私は懐中電灯が見つけられません。
> I can't find my/the torch. (speaker is in the dark).

I am aware that られます is another way of saying able to but can you say

> 私は懐中電灯が見つけできません。

instead?

Can the two be used interchangeably?

Comment: 見つけできません is ungrammatical. It should be 見つけることができません. See this link: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2689/%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%82%8b-versus-v%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b-form

Comment: @user3856370 - I don’t understand why that answer in the linked question got so many upvotes.

Comment: @aguijonazo Hmm, maybe I should have read through all the answers before linking. I suspect that it's a combination of historical accumulation and the fact that it was endorsed by Derek Schaab who seems to have been a well respected contributor in the past. Would you say there was any element of truth to the most upvoted answer?

Comment: @user3856370 - No.

Comment: Check this answer: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39307/45630

Comment: OP, I think you need to rewrite your question.  While the existing answer from @naruto is helpful, it ultimately doesn't address what you're wondering, which is actually the difference between ～(ら)れます and **Verb** +ことができます.

Answer (score 1):

懐中電灯が見つけできません is ungrammatical, because the only word できる can directly follow is a suru-verb such as 運転, 発見 and 勉強. 見つけ is not a suru-verb (you cannot say 見つけする).

If you really want to use both 見つける and できる, you have to say 懐中電灯**を**見つける**ことが**できません. In your case, it's simplest and most natural to say 懐中電灯が見つかりません.